# Rotating through multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, slideshow

I'm trying to do a simple slideshow with the following javascript code, but it is not working for me. I've triple checked the spelling, made sure that all the elements correlate with my HTML.

Javascript:

```
var pic_rotation = ["pic1.jpg", "pic2.jpg", "pic3.jpg"],
    cap_rotation = ["caption 1", "caption 2", "caption 3"];
var int = 0;

function rotatePicCap(){
    if (int < pic_rotation.length){
        int++;
    }
    else if (int == pic_rotation.length){
        int = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("pic").src = pic_rotation[int];
    document.getElementById("cap").innerHTML = pic_rotation[int];
}

setInterval(function slideShow(){rotatePicCap()}, 4000);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="pic1.jpg" alt="Picture" id="pic">
    <div id="cap">caption 1</div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on why this wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine how it's written for the most part. The issue is like @CertainPerformance says though (the if-statement).

You are checking and incrementing `int` before displaying your information. So at the start with `int` being 0, you first display `pic2` due to `int` incrementing to 1 before displaying. Your if-statement checks properly that `int` is less than the length but then you increment it before displaying.

Make the following change and you are fine:

```
function rotatePicCap(){
    if (int == pic_rotation.length){
        int = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("pic").src = pic_rotation[int];
    document.getElementById("cap").innerHTML = pic_rotation[int];
    int++;
}
```

This will still increment but you will do a check before. If `int` is greater then you restart at 0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if (int < pic_rotation.length) int++;
```

Look at your browser console - it'll tell you what the problem is. On the last iteration, `int` will be the same as the length of the array. But for an array of length 3, `arr[3]` is undefined.

Better to use modulo:

```
function rotatePicCap(){
  int = (int + 1) % pic_rotation.length;
```

One other thing - only use `innerHTML` when you're deliberately using or inserting HTML markup (which can have security and encoding problems). When you're setting or retrieving text values, use `textContent` instead.

```
document.getElementById("cap").textContent = pic_rotation[int];
```

Comment: Why is modulo better?

Comment: It allows for a concise one-line transformation of the variable in question.